# Libgdx Coordinates after rotateAround camera

Tags: java, android, libgdx

After the camera rotation, the coordinates were confusing to me.

I have a camera a character and a map.
This player walks only in the directions: north (90 °), south (270 °), east (0 °), west (180 °).

[image: Before rotation]

After rotating the camera from the position of the player 'camera.rotateAround (..., ..., ...)' the player starts to move in new directions as a result of rotation.

[image: After rotation]

Is there a way to reposition the original back to the coordinates without moving the map to the original position?

- Note: The track map is temporary then have these loosely glued edges.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to store rotation angle of map.
Then when player moves you need to take account rotation angle of map.

```
camera.rotatearound(...)//I guess you rotating +90 or -90 in this game 
maprotation+=... //+90 or -90 depends on side you turn.
//i ll assume rotation direction is counter clock wise.
```

Now you know rotation so you can set player movement with a trigonometry.

in player.moveup(float maprotation) method or whereever you wrote codes for moving to north.

```
x+=MathUtils.cosDeg(90-maprotation)*speed;//90 degree for moving up
y+=MathUtils.sinDeg(90-maprotation)*speed;// - maprotation for correction
```

[image]

As you can see when camera rotating also directions rotating. So you just need to subtract map rotation to correct.

[image]

Comment: Thank you mr. Deniz

Comment: Hi Deniz, I'm studying trigonometry as you mentioned. Even so I had another problem. Could you help me, please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028834/libgdx-fixed-point-after-camera-rotatearound